# Cycles render get overexposed last second

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am rendering in view port and render is ok. but when i do final render it gets overexposed.

I am using image based lighting. I think there might be a node issue.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4xg4.jpg)

Comment: i think you have set up some post processing nodes that is changing the scene after it gets rendered in the last second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check out if you have the same setup or you have some extra nodes in there! i think those nodes are being processed after the render is done and changing your render

Comment: Thank you so much. There was a glare node in between causing the issue! thank you for solving this.